# Выравнивание картинки по размеру блока

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!

Использую bootstrap для верстки. Как выравнять по ширине картинку с родительским блоком?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка в этом блоке:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-mg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="/img/template/taxi_logo_02.jpg" alt="логотип" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

А за ним блок к контентом:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-mg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ijh">
    <p>Здесь будет расположен весь остальной контент.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Саму верстку целиком можете посмотреть здесь(уже нельзя).

Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените изображение на заглушку (т. к. путь неверный). Например [так](https://placehold.it/).

Comment: удалите - .ijh { background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);} и добавьте .telo2{background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);}

Comment: @Other, не понял вас. У меня изображение видно.

Comment: Комментарий устарел. Когда был сниппет, то там изображение не загружалось.

Comment: @soledar10, я вначале так сделал, а потом обратил внимание на ваш комментарий. Это оказался абсолютно верный вариант!!!! Спасибо.

Только я не пойму, почему div который является родительским (telo2) является более узким, чем дочерний элемент row?

PS Оформите свой комментарий как ответ :)

Comment: @ВладиславМСК - потому что .row { margin-right: -15px;  margin-left: -15px;}

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, у вас там нет картинки, это всего лишь отступ другого блока:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блок этот вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у него на картинке выше я отметил класс, который имеет цвет фона. Решить это можно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другими словами, просто удалите тот класс, `ijh`, из кода в своем `style.css`, он вам не нужен, так как внутри блока с этим классом другие блоки уже имеют класс `m_mid_tpl`, который точно также задает вам цвет фона со значением `rgb(235, 235, 235)`.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, вы абсолютно правы, я это понимаю и сделал так умышленно. Потому что иначе выходит вот такая вещь: https://habrastorage.org/files/b8e/2f9/b35/b8e2f9b359084c30b85bc2ce02534125.JPG

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, по-быстрому проверил в Мозилле и Хроме - все ок, никаких пустых мест. Так или иначе, решать заливкой фона в блоке row  - это не верный путь. Я бы советовал изменить либо структуру блоков внутри него таким образом, чтобы этого пустого места не оставалось, либо, если уж совсем никак не получается, менять отступы в bootstrap, но не в самом файле фреймворка, а через подключение своего негоего custom.css и переопределения в нем нужных вам классов и тд.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, а, ну и если сделаете более крупный скриншот и с открытым инспектором, то возможно смогу помочь с изменением внутренней структуры, так как пока что не пойму, откуда у вас такая лакуна там берется.

Comment: просто я уже все исправил, а файлы автоматически загружаются на сервер. Понял все ошибки, буду думать над корректным решением. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

В верстке на которую вы дали ссылку и изображение в топике - это не проблема респонсивного изображения бутстрапа . В ссылке на сайт вы применяете фоновый цвет к бутстраповской колонке .col-*-* образующей сетку. У вас это стиль:

```
.ijh {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}
```

Этого делать не нужно, так как в колонке присутствуют паддинги, которые имеют обратные отступы из за родительского .row

Для того чтобы применить фоновое изображение или цвет внутри колонки, применяйте стиль ко внутреннему диву.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12 ijh">
      не правильно
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="ijh">
        правильно
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ему не нужно размещать этот класс где-либо еще, так как внутри этой строки у него есть блоки с классом `m_mid_tpl`, который и задает фон всем четырем внутренним блокам. Нужно просто удалить класс `ijh`, как я уже написал в своем ответе чуть раньше вас http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624949/218094

Comment: @kizoso, по-моему, сейчас опробую и отпишусь по результату.

Comment: @kizoso, ваш метод приводит к тому же результату, что и вариант Станислава. Ответ я дал под его постом.

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб изображение не выходило за пределы блока, выставьте ему max-width;

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Картинка в `div` [`body > div > div:nth-child(3) > div`], у него три класса (`col-lg-12`, `col-sm-12`, `col-xs-12`), в которых прописано:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Сбросьте их у `div`-контейнера.

Comment: я попробую заключить картинку в div и задать отрицательные отступы.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, зачем? Просто уберите отступы у этого `div`.

Comment: спасибо, это работает, но я нашел более лучший способ :)

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, ОК, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Если изображене выходит за пределы блок, нужно родительскому блоку придать свойство:

```
overflow: hidden;
```